# Phase unwrapping of data with nans

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to unwrap the phase of a signal using np.unwrap, but the signal has some np.nan values... how do I remedy this?
Is there a way for np.unwrap to ignore the np.nans?

Answer (score 0):

Try masking the `np.nan` and then run `np.unwrap`, like this:

```
a[~np.isnan(a)] = np.unwrap(a[~np.isnan(a)])
```

OR, replace `nan` with `0` and then unwrap it.

```
a[np.isnan(a)] = 0 
a[~np.isnan(a)] = np.unwrap(a[~np.isnan(a)])
```

Comment: thanks! is a the signal/array? i am trying that but unfortunately the phase still does not look upwrapped :/

Comment: `a` is the numpy array.

Comment: i have a 2D array though.. and the ~np.isnan(a) is making it 1D... how do i keep the 2 dimensionality?

Comment: Can we replace the `np.nan` with 0 and then unwrap the array? Would that be ok for your case? Check my updated answer.

Comment: @alagnak32 Please let me know if the answer worked?